# Assigning action to Parent elements only, exclude child elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How to use jquery selectors to select parent only but exclude child

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="element">
    <img src="something.jpg"/>
    <a href="somelink">Some link</a>
    <p>Blah blah...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <img src="something2.jpg"/>
    <a href="somelink2">Some link2</a>
    <p>Blah blah...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

How can I trigger alert("Hi") only if user clicks on (div "element") but not when < a > and < img > are clicked

```
                    $("#container").delegate(".element", "click", function(){
                        alert("Hi");
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events bubble up the DOM unless you explicitly stop their propagation. I recommend that you try to work with this, not against it. That said, if you insist, examine [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) to make sure that the `div.element` was clicked, and not one of its children:

```
$("#container").delegate(".element", "click", function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).hasClass("element")) return;
    alert("Hi");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/JMDLq/

Answer (score 0):

I've just answered the same question yesterday, search a bit before asking.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10440234/1331430

Just replace the 2 ID selectors there by `$('.element')` and you're all set.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input.. believe me.. ive searched alot... i know it is important to keep the knowledge base streamlined... however my searches couldn't yield a solution that worked. ive googled a bunch like: jquery select parent exclude child... came up with no workable solution